# Google Authenticator my Android app

Tags: android, google-authenticator

I am making an Android app, but I want to use the functionality of the Google Authenticator app in my app, in a way that the users won't have to start the Google Authenticator app to get the login. I want to kind of integrate it. Is this possible? Is this feasible? I did find the Google Authenticator Source, but I have no idea where to start. So if it is possible and feasible, where do I start?

Comment: But i don't understand, why you need use Google Authenticator?

Comment: I am not quite sure why, but my company uses it for some secure connections, however, I only know about it since this morning. So I have no idea what it does exactly. I am assuming it's a random number generator of sorts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it no possible** use Google Authenticator for own purposes.

Comment: is it still not available ? any idea?